# SVG Text not showing

Tags: html, css, svg

My CSS is meant to show the user's Initials as their profile picture, however, the style used in tandem with the SVG does not show the text. If I separate both instances I see the text.

```css
.card_background_img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #1B2149;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 150px; background-color: #ffffff; margin: 0 auto; border-radius: 8px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 13%; box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);">
                    <div class="card_background_img"></div>
                    <!--<div-->
                    <!--    style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: #868d9b;background: url('');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;background-position: center;border: 5px solid #ffffff;border-radius: 120px;float: left;margin-top: -60px;margin-left: 30px;">-->
                    <!--</div>-->
                    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: #868d9b; background: url('<svg width='150' height='150' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='#868d9b'/><text x='50%' y='50%' dominant-baseline='middle' text-anchor='middle' fill='#ffffff' font-family='Arial' font-size='60' font-weight='bold'>BIO</text></svg>'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 120px; float: left; margin-top: -60px; margin-left: 30px;">
</div>
                </div>
```

Kindly help, because I feel I am missing something on the nose and can't figure out what. Frontend is not my bread and butter so go easy on me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the svg as a background but you already have a background. I seperated them out and tried the following. It worked for me:

```css
.card_background_img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #1B2149;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 150px; background-color: #ffffff; margin: 0 auto; border-radius: 8px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 13%; box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);">
        <div class="card_background_img"></div> 
                    <!-- <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: #868d9b;background: url('');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;background-position: center;border: 5px solid #ffffff;border-radius: 120px;float: left;margin-top: -60px;margin-left: 30px;">
                    </div> -->                    
                    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: #868d9b; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center; border: 5px solid #ffeeff; border-radius: 120px; float: left; margin-top: -60px; margin-left: 30px;">

                    <svg width='150' height='150' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
                        <text x='50%' y='50%' dominant-baseline='middle' text-anchor='middle' fill='#ffeeff' font-family='Arial' font-size='60' font-weight='bold'>BIO</text>
                    </svg>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works for me now. So if I understand the problem correctly the first background rule canceled the second. pardon me. I like to know how problems come about, that helps inform future caution

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand why the background was set using a url and then a svg nested inside that. You have the background set to a color and then again the background set to a url. Inside the url tag, you have the <svg>. I don't think you can do that. If you use the url tag, you need to give an actual file. The file can be a .svg but here you are creating an svg. I could be wrong about that but that is my understanding of how it works. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that helps. Thank you